# What summary statistics can be applied to the results from a multiple choice question?

Tags: survey, descriptive-statistics

I have a list of answers given for a multiple choice question. For **multiple choice** I mean that from a set of possible answers given, more than one can be chosen. For other answers with single choice I produce a percentage of the answers given to a particular choice. But I cannot use a percentage for this case when there are multiple choices. Eg. 10 participants, two possible answers, each respondent answers yes to both choices, a1=10 and a2=10, so with the percentages you would have a1=50% and a2=50%.

What are the best concise ways to display this multiple choice data?

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to summarize the data?  Depending on your purpose, it might be that % choosing a given choice for a question with multiple possible answers is viable.  Why do you assume it is not a viable approach?

Comment: @JoelW., I am looking for a number of approaches to choose from. Which different purposes exist. I have the data and want to know the various ways to handle the data to produce some type of % or other output in a concise manner.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if any question choices are more confusing to high scoring candidates, for example?  If so, percent choosing a choice might work well.  It is difficult to suggest approaches without knowing your goal or purpose. Can you tell us more about what you want to learn from the data?

Comment: @JoelW., let's say there are 3 respondents, for 4 choices (a,b,c,d), and respondents 1->(a,d),2->(b,d),3->(c,d). So each one gives a different answer but all give at the same time choice d. What statistics can we put on this data?

Comment: Why are do doing the item analyses? Looking for good items? Trying to help test takers improve?

Comment: @JoelW., understand the respondent tendencies, what overlaps exist, which overlaps do not exist, any stats for the pairings, etc

Comment: Would the percent choosing each choice serve that purpose, even if the numbers add up to more than 100% due to the ability to choose more than one choice?

Comment: They might add up to more than 100%. These are all perfectly fine possibilities since the question is open ended.

Answer (score 1):

A [contingency table](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/book/export/html/102) might just be what you need. Using it, we can see the variables' proportion, we can see the overlaps, correlation, and dependence/independence between the variables.

In a multiple choice context, each choice can be considered a binary (yes/no) variable. Suppose the question have four choices, then we can create a four-way contingency table from the data.